# What did the animals eat when they emerged from the ark?

Tags: apologetics, flood-of-noah

Given that Noah had to rescue 2 of a kind of every animal and [fit them all in the ark](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1344/how-did-all-the-animals-fit-into-noahs-ark), and given that he would've had to feed them while they were in his captivity:

If after the flood there were only mating pairs of each species in existence, what did the predators eat? If they ate *any* of their natural prey, the prey wouldn't survive, to be followed shortly by starving predators.

So once he set them free, what did they eat?

Comment: You should amend this to say "for those who do not believe the story is a medaphor, or allegory" otherwise I don't think you'll get the answers you are going for

Comment: It has been [discussed on Meta](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/480/should-we-allow-im-making-a-point-questions) that these types of questions are discouraged. There is little to nothing useful that can come from this. Feel free to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1167/christianity) though!

Comment: For all we know, a bunch of them DID get eaten! However if Noah brought along food for the time in the ark I'm sure it helped tide them over while they reproduced enough in the outside world to survive. If God made them cooperative to all come to the ark in pairs I'm sure he could arrange a little bit of social engineering afterwards too.

Comment: [Magic!](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zTr_IgdNjJY) (probably not for the firebrand)

Comment: Rabbinic tradition and literature has commentary on this.  I encourage you to ask your question on judaism.stackexchange.com.